# How can i store Text Data in String Arrays in Windows Store Application

Tags: c#

I want to Store Text file into String Arrays , when i used console Application  it had not work

```
string [] a = System.IO.File.ReadTextLines(@"Path");
```

once I tried this method in Windows Store it had not work

Comment: The `File` class has no such method. Perhaps you mean `ReadAllLines`?

Comment: yes but this worked in console app , once i tried it in Windows store it had not work

Comment: Console apps and Windows Store apps use different set of APIs.

Comment: @LukášNeoproud  So how i can solve it :)

Comment: try using any equivalent functions like readAlllines.

Comment: @AliTorabi how can i ?

Comment: string mytext = File.ReadAllLines("path");

Comment: 'FILE' does not exist